# Icon in Mint does not work but application works when called directly - Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, kde-plasma, linux-mint

I am running Mint 17.1 (Rebecca) KDE (64-bit)

The problem is that the icon for the application Intellij IDEA does not work but it works when I call the application directly by:

```
cd /opt/idea-IU-141.1010.3/bin/
./idea.sh
```

The first time that I ran the code above I got the error:

> 'tools.jar' seems to be not in IDEA classpath. Please ensure JAVA_HOME points to JDK rather than JRE.

Pretty straightforward message. I went to to ~/.bashrc and add:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/
```

And reload in terminal:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Then, when I ran again:

```
./idea.sh
```

It worked as expected... but when I press the icon in the Launcher Menu, I got the same error as described above!

Why I still having the problem with the classpath? I also reboot the system, but I got the error again.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the application with the launcher, `.bashrc` is not read if the shell used to run the shell script is not bash. You may add

```
JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_45/
```

to `/opt/idea-IU-141.1010.3/idea.sh` itself.

Comment: You are correct! I have not noticed that was the sh shell in the shebang of the file. Thank you!